# Error in installing packages from RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-13.04, rstudio-server

I have been trying to install the package "doby" from RStudio (ver 0.98.501 ) on ubuntu 13.04 but it keeps throwing the following warning and the package does not get installed.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘doBy’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

I have followed all the instructions given here :
http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-packages/

Can someone please suggest where I might be going wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried to update your version of R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu, please see [this README for Ubuntu from CRAN](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu) --- it will allow you to get to the current version of R (today 3.0.2, in a few days 3.0.3) with mininal effort.

Once you have a current R version, getting the doBy package (which depends on it) installed is a piece of cake too.

If however you prefer to stay with your version of R, you can manually fetch an older version of doBy [from its CRAN archive](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/doBy/). Download to, say, `/tmp` and run `R CMD INSTALL`by hand on it.

Answer (score 2):

From http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doBy/index.html, package `doBy` depends on R version 3.0 and above. Your R version is 2.15.2. You will need to install a later version of `R`, and then change the [settings](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/versions_of_r) in `Rstudio` to target the updated version.